# Ошибка 1064 SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня ошибка SQL syntax error. Почеркивает почему-то слово `system` (таблица в базе данных на скриншоте видно). Не пойму, почему выдаёт ошибку.

```
Sum - double,
billing_date - date,
Остальное всё - varchar;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: проверьте поле sum.currency

Comment: system - это [зарезервированное слово](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S), вы не можете использовать его как название таблицы.

Comment: После `sum` не точка, а запятая

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как минимум в MariaDB `system` нормально работает, только что проверил (автору бы версию mysql уточнить)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я поставил там запятую и слово system взял в ковычки вот так system и всё заработало :), благодарю

Comment: SYSTEM (R) added in 8.0.3 (reserved) - добавлено только в 8й версии. тем более, у автора таблица уже создана

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis создаём таблицу в 5.7, обновляем СУБД до 8.0.3, profit.

Comment: @artem55555p Пожалуйста, не добавляйте метку "база данных". Почитайте в каких случаях она используется в кратком описании к метке.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это само собой. но у автора она уже создана, по этому проблема была явно не в ней и использовать его возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> почеркивает почему-то слово system

`system` – это зарезервированное слово

К тому же, вас опечатка в запросе, после `sum` явно должна быть запятая:

```
... sum. currency, ...
//    ^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я поставил там запятую и слово system взял в ковычки вот так `system` и всё заработало :), благодарю

Comment: @TerletskiyAlexander, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)